# Javascript not working on heroku app with ruby 2.1.5 and rails 4.2.0

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

The app's javascrip working on a localhost but when I up to heroku it stops.
I using ruby 2.1.5 and rails 4.2.0, also using gem bootstrap.

I try a lot of thing, like

```
 config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
 config.serve_static_assets = true
 config.assets.compress = true
```

and some gems but nothing works

the console give this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefinedapplication-86a70362c3062e6b111a577822640eed.js:1 
aplicationReadyapplication-86a70362c3062e6b111a577822640eed.js:17 (anonymous function)
application-86a70362c3062e6b111a577822640eed.js:2 
capplication-86a70362c3062e6b111a577822640eed.js:2 
u.fireWithapplication-86a70362c3062e6b111a577822640eed.js:2 
se.extend.readyapplication-86a70362c3062e6b111a577822640eed.js:1 r
```

How do I need to work?

Comment: What errors do you see in the browser console?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefinedapplication-86a70362c3062e6b111a577822640eed.js:1 aplicationReadyapplication-86a70362c3062e6b111a577822640eed.js:17 (anonymous function)application-86a70362c3062e6b111a577822640eed.js:2 capplication-86a70362c3062e6b111a577822640eed.js:2 u.fireWithapplication-86a70362c3062e6b111a577822640eed.js:2 se.extend.readyapplication-86a70362c3062e6b111a577822640eed.js:1 r

Comment: Please edit the question and include this information there.